# How to call only one code by condition if when user enter any data

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

I have `textField` i want that when user enter data and presses space then it should add new row in `tableView` it works fine but i also want that on `textFieldDidEndEditing` it should also add row but when there is no space press by user right now in my code if any user pressed space code it add rows also and then other row for `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

```
    -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField==tagTextField) {
        [self showAnimationBack];
    }

    if (textField.tag==2) {
        if (textField.text.length > 0 || ![tagTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
            [tagArray addObject:tagInputField.text];
            [tableView reloadData];

            tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.contentSize.height);

            [tableView.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
            [tableView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
            tableView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
            tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;

            [self showAnimationBack];

            float y = descriptionTextImageView.frame.origin.y;

            float yp = publishButton.frame.origin.y;

            NSLog(@"Y is %2.f",y);

            if (y==405.00) {
            [descriptionTextImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(48,y+30,250,90)];
            [publishButton setFrame:CGRectMake(40,yp+30,250, 50)];
            }

            else{
                y=y+30;
                [descriptionTextImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(48,y,250,90)];
                [publishButton setFrame:CGRectMake(40,yp+30,250, 50)];
            }
      }
}
}
```

And Other when space is pressed

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {


    if (textField.tag==2) {


   if ( [string isEqualToString:@" " ]){


    if (textField.text.length > 0 || ![tagTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [tagArray addObject:tagInputField.text];
        [tableView reloadData];
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.contentSize.height);

        [tableView.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
        [tableView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        tableView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
        tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;

        float y = descriptionTextImageView.frame.origin.y;

        float yp = publishButton.frame.origin.y;

        NSLog(@"Y is %2.f",y);

        if (y==405.00) {
            [descriptionTextImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(48,y+30,250,90)];
            [publishButton setFrame:CGRectMake(40,yp+30,250, 50)];
        }
        else{
            y=y+30;

        [descriptionTextImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(48,y,250,90)];
            [publishButton setFrame:CGRectMake(40,yp+30,250, 50)];
        }
        [self showAnimationBack];
    }

    }
   else {

    return YES;
    }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Can you tel me whether your textFieldDidEndEditing is being called??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Are you saying that if a user presses "space" then ends editing you get 2 rows added? Is that what you're trying to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I could not completely get what are you actually looking for. If you are trying to avoid adding of new if user simply presses space bar without entering any other character then below piece of code can help you out:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string { 

    NSString *resultingString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: range withString: string];
    NSCharacterSet *whitespaceSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
    if  ([resultingString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:whitespaceSet].location == NSNotFound)      {
        return YES;
    }  else  {
        return NO;
    }
 }
```

Comment: no i want that user enters data in textfield then moves to another textfield then it should also enter new row

Comment: and when user press space then it should also insert rows

Answer (score 0):

use uitextview it's work's what you want

Answer (score 0):

I tink u should call **textFieldShouldReturn**

**textFieldDidEndEditing** is fired when the textfield resigns it's first responder and **textFieldShouldReturn** is fired when the return button is pressed.

Mayb your textfield is never resigning its firstResponder. You can check it  by putting some debug output or by navigating out of the textfield with a touch - eg start typing then just touch outside of the field to force it to resign firstResponder.